# Should Backbone collection 'create' add new model to collection with id from server included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, handlebars.js, fetch

In my Backbone view here, I want to be able to immediately add my model to my collection with an `'id'` attribute included in the newly created model.  In other words, I need to have access to this `'id'` right away.  With the `id` available, my `removeCategory` method can work.  To "solve" that problem, I tried to add the line `this.collection.fetch()` directly below `this.collection.add(model);`, but it gave me very bad UI (the new `<li>` wouldn't even render, etc), plus it seems like very bad coding practice anyway.

I'm relatively new with Backbone, so I'm not sure if `create` (save/add) should automatically add the model to the collection with an `id` or not.  If it should, then there must be something wrong with the JSON data I'm receiving from my Rails RESTful API.  If `create` does NOT do that, then how can I instantly get access to this specific newly created model, with an `id` (other than by refreshing the browser -- ugh!)?  I need the `id` for `<li data-id={{id}}></li>` in my Handlebars template as soon as I invoke the "addCategory" method.

Also (& this might be a related problem), when I do `model.fetch();`, I get back the model's entire collection, plus that newly-created server-side model without an `id`.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
window.CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({

  index_template: HandlebarsTemplates['categories/index'],

  events: {
    'click .delete': 'removeCategory',
    'click .category_add': 'addCategory'
  },
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection.fetch();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render);
  },

  show: function() {
    $("#categorymodal").modal();
  },

  addCategory: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // I wrote the next three lines here explicitly rather than using 'create'
    var model = new Category({ name: $(this.el).find('.category_name').val() });
    model.save();
    this.collection.add(model);
    this.show();
  },

  removeCategory: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(e.target).parents('li').data('id');
    var model = this.collection.where({ id: id })[0];
    this.collection.remove(model);
    if (model) { model.destroy(); }
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.index_template());

    this.collection.models.forEach(function(cat) {
      var li_template = HandlebarsTemplates['categories/show']
      $(this.el).find('.categories').append(li_template({
        id: cat.toJSON().id,
        name: cat.toJSON().name
      }));
    }, this);

    return this;
  }

});
```

Here is my `#create` action in Rails....

```
def create
  @category = Category.create(category_params)
  render :nothing => true
end
```

I am using `jbuilder` to provide the JSON from the Rails API.

Here is my Backbone model and collection...

```
window.Category = Backbone.Model.extend({

  urlRoot: "categories"

});


window.Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: Category,
  url : function() {
    return 'categories';
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem.  It was in my Rails controller, not with Backbone `create`.  I changed my `#create` action from this...

```
def create
  @category = Category.create(category_params)
  render :nothing => true
end
```

...to this....

```
def create
  @category = Category.create(category_params)
  redirect_to category_path(@category)
end
```

...with my show action being this...

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

...that provided me with `http://localhost:3000/categories/752.json`.  I've gotta make sure my backend is providing what I need JSON-wise!